# mat-selection-list not working with *ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I'm trying to use a mat-selection-list as an option in a mat-menu:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit() {
   items: string[] = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']
   constructor(){}
}
```

```
<button [matMenuTriggerFor]="settings">
<\button>

<mat-menu #settings="matMenu">
   <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="items">Items<\button>
<\mat-menu>

<mat-menu #items="matMenu">
   <mat-selection-list>
      <mat-list-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item">
         {{item}}
      <\mat-list-option>
   <\mat-selection-list>
<\mat-menu>
```

When I click the button, the menu appears, in which the element "Items" can be chosen. In "Items", I'm expecting to see a list of the items `item1`, `item2` and `item3`. However, nothing is displayed and the following error is thrown:

```
Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object [object Object] of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

How is my array `items` not suitable for ngFor? What am I missing? The list is populated correctly if I add each mat-list-option manually, but with ngFor it's causing me problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possible issues:

1. Your use of `#settings="matMenu"` and `#items="matMenu"` sets the value of both `settings` and `items` to the same reference of `matMenu`, which is probably not what you want. From the docs:

> How Angular assigns values to template variables
> ...
> If the variable specifies a name on the right-hand side, such as `#var="ngModel"`, the variable refers to the directive or component on the element with a matching exportAs name.

https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables#how-angular-assigns-values-to-template-variables

You should just use `#settings` and `#items`. However...

2. `#items` in your template will override the `items: string[]` in your component. Pick a different variable name for your `<mat-menu>` element -- maybe `#itemsMenu`, for example.